# Custom directive for form validation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to validate a number according to its min and max value through `angularJS`
this is the custom directive, I first tried with max that provide angularJs for input number validation it works with static number not with binding data. That's why i thought about custom directive

```
.directive('ngMax', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
        scope.$watch(attr.ngMax, function(){
            if (ctrl.$isDirty) ctrl.$setViewValue(ctrl.$viewValue);
        });
        var maxValidator = function(value) {
          var max = scope.$eval(attr.ngMax) || Infinity;
          if (!isEmpty(value) && value > max) {
            ctrl.$setValidity('ngMax', false);
            return undefined;
          } else {
            ctrl.$setValidity('ngMax', true);
            return value;
          }
        };

        ctrl.$parsers.push(maxValidator);
        ctrl.$formatters.push(maxValidator);
    }
};
});
```

and in the view :

```
<div class="modal-body" >
    title: {{book.title}}<br>
    price: {{book.price}}<br>
    quantity: {{book.nbr_exemplaires}}
    <form name= "myForm" ng-submit= "addToCart(book, quantity, <%= current_user.id %>)" novalidate >
      <input type="number" min="1"  ng-max="{{book.nbr_exemplaires}}" name= "quantite" ng-model="quantity" required  >
      <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.quantite.$error.required">
        <span ng-show="myForm.quantite.$error.required">quantity is required!</span>
      </span>


  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button  class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid ">Save changes</button>
  </div>
  </form>
```

I could not understand where is the problem

Comment: I will warn you about using "NG" prefix: if you have to upgrade to angularJS 10.7, who will know if they will implement a ngMax directive? In this case you will encounter some errors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid X/Y questions, when you try something and it doesn't work, try to address that first. That's good that you provided a broader context, so specifically to your question, built-in `max` provides everything that you need:

```
<input type="number" max="{{max}}" ng-model="foo">
```

and you can set `max` dynamically, for example:

```
$scope.max = 10;
```